# ¿Dos consultas a la misma tabla para diferentes filas?

Tags: php, mysql

necesito hacer dos consultas sobre la misma tabla pero diferentes filas. En este caso de seguidos_perfil del id_perfil 63 y de seguidores_perfil del id_perfil 66

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con el siguiente prepare pero no devuelve la informacion que puede estar mal?

```
include "conexion.php";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT L.seguidos_perfil, V.seguidores_perfil FROM perfiles WHERE L.id_perfil = ? AND V.id_perfil = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$idLogin,$idVisitado);
```

Comment: `L` y `V` no están definidos en ningún lado. Podrías hacer un `UNION` de dos subqueries que retornen una fila cada una con dos columnas: nombre y valor (obtendrías un valor en cada fila), o un `CROSS JOIN` de dos subqueries que retornen un valor cada una (obtendrías un valor en cada columna y una sola fila).

Comment: También podrías usar **IN(n1, n2,.....)** para tus caso sería: **SELECT seguidos_perfil, seguidores_perfil FROM perfiles WHERE id_perfil in (?,?)**

Comment: Hay tantas cosas mal en ese query (y esa tabla) que no se por donde empezar... PAra empezar, ese query asi escrito no anda.. L y V no son nada... sacando eso de lado, con un OR funcionaria. Pero, tener una lista de seguidores o seguidos en la misma tabla, es algo que esta muy pero muy mal. Estudia sobre normalizacion de bases de datos.. eso datos deberian estar en otra tabla, y entonces no tendrias problemas para hacer tu query....

Comment: @federico-nuñez pudiste resolverlo? Si te han quedado dudas avisame y las vemos.

Comment: @nachospiu Disculpa la demora, estuve leyendo pero no creo que me sirva ya que necesito dos valores el de seguidores y seguidos en string por separado y por el codigo consecuente.. Explico lo que quiero hacer, necesito insertar valores en esos dos campos pero primero los selecciono para verificarlos y despues realizo un UPDATE pasando el string que recibo a Array, hacer los cambios y luego pasarlo otra vez a string. No digo que sea lo mas correcto pero veo que me sirva, igual te leo si me tenes que desburrar.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por el consejo, ahora mismo busco informacion sobre "normalizacion de bases de datos"

Comment: Todo eso que haces, es justamente lo que esta mal.. ese campo no debe ser un string... ese campo debe ser otra tabla.... y de ahi, que tengas montones de problemas....

Comment: @gbianchi Ya entendi, ahora voy a probar a partir de otras tablas y con clave foranea